# Kombu disconnects on publish

Tags: python, rabbitmq, kombu

I'm having trouble publishing messages using kombu 4.1. My use case is that I have a server that collects messages from a rabbitmq queue (queue 1), performs some processing task and then republishes them to a different queue, (queue 2). I have no problem consuming from queue 1 but when I try to publish to queue 2 there is an intermittent fault that causes me to disconnect from rabbitmq. I've activated both retries and the combined ConsumerProducerMixin but the problem remains. I have also published this issue on the kombu github page to no avail:- https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/857

Does anyone have any insight into this issue, will it be fixed in kombu 4.2, is there any work around that doesn't involve switching to another library?

Thank You

Comment: I have found a temporary fix for this. I put the publish command in a for loop with a try catch designed to repeat the publish command up to 30 times manually if it fails to publish. This seems like replication of the retry command however. Does anyone have any further insight into this?

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer on why this is happening, but two workarounds that seem to solve the problem for us.

- Set `heartbeat=0` when opening a new Connection (but maybe you need the hearbeats).
- Downgrade kombu version to `v4.0.2`. As stated [here](https://medium.com/squad-engineering/two-years-with-celery-in-production-bug-fix-edition-22238669601d), `task_publish_retry_policy` seems to be broken from `kombu==4.1.0`

I hope this helps!

Comment: There is a third work around where I added a try except to the publish command so that when it fails I reconnect to rabbitmq and retry to send the message. This manual version of the task_publish_retry_policy seems to work for now but I'm still waiting on a full fix in a future version of the library.